# How to add a field dynamically in an existing mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am making an app where the admin has control to add/remove fields in a form. I have implemented the logic to add fields like 1.) any text input 2.) any dropdown 3.)any date inputs by clicking
add/remove button in ReactJS . It is a real-time application . According to my knowledge I have to update the schema with new field to see the new updated fields  in DB .

**So my question is how do Admin achieve that with the click of add/remove a field in real-time , the schema gets updated automatically ?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.